# Sql server, time format

Tags: sql-server

I have recently starter working with sql server instead of mysql.

I have a time column which I've noticed stores time as such: hh:mm:ss:nnnnnnn
Thing is I only want to to store hh:mm:ss, and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I do apologize if this is really obvious, I have had a long day and my searches did not return anything that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time has a precision parameter which is "fractional second precision" so if you need `hh:mm:ss` you have to use `time(0)` as datatype

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be it, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

use the [Time datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) which is available since 2008 onwards

Answer (score 1):

If on SQL 2008, use the time datatype, and just store the hh:mm:ss; the nanoseconds will be 0.  Just display the value back in the desired format in your presentation layer.

If on SQL 2005 (or older), you'll need to store the data as a datetime, and input the date version as some constant (usually 1900-01-01).  Again, format the data at the presentation layer, not at the database.